# How to deploy only the updated components instead of the whole repo when using CircleCI

Tags: git, deployment, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, circleci

I am setting up CI for a large Git repository using CircleCI. I want to deploy changes to develop regularly. However, since the repo is very large, deploying the whole repo will take a long time.

How can I programmatically identify the changes and deploy those only to save deployment time? For example, somehow find out the latest deployment commit, compare it with the current commit and only deploy the files that are changed between the two.

Comment: How big is the whole Git repo (in MB) and how long does it take to deploy the whole thing? Are you using Git as a deployment tool?

Comment: As of now, it is about 600MB and it will take about half an hour to deploy. I need to clean it up and use a build tool I think but the code base is big and complicated and I'm looking for a temporary solution until I find the time to do that.

Comment: What is the size of the codebase if you do a shallow clone? I wonder if you have a lot of history that is irrelevant for deployments.

Comment: I wonder also if you have some large and infrequently changing files that could be moved into a separate repo or a separately deployed app.

Comment: There are a lot of files that are not changed frequently and could probably be moved out of the repo (e.g., resources). So you're suggesting I create a separate repo for those? Getting them out of the repo can probably shrink the repo size. I just need to figure out a way to deploy the two repos to the same folder without breaking the other

Comment: If you need those files for your tests, then that might not give you any advantage if you have to then clone both repos inside your CI. Look at shallow cloning first, in case that gives you a big advantage to start with.